# How to add elements to ScrollView if the designer is too small?

Tags: ios, visual-studio, xamarin, interface-builder, scrollview

I have a ViewController which contains a ScrollView and I'm trying to make a form menu so I need multiple labels and text fields.
I've been using the designer to do that.

The ScrollView will allow the user to scroll vertically, I already have many elements in the View but I need to add more.

The problem is that the size of the parent ViewController have a fixed size in the designer and because of that I reached the situation where I need to add elements under a label but there is just no space in the designer where I can put it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

hmmm.. not sure how this will carry over to tamarin/visual-studio, but in Xcode Interface Builder you can set the View Controller Simulated Size to "Freeform" --- and then set it as tall as you wish. Well, it *may* have a limit, but I just tested it and made it as tall as 5,000 pts. After laying everything out, you can set it back to "normal" size. At runtime, it will size itself however you've set the constraints.

Other alternatives...

1. Design your elements in "containing" views, and then add them in either dynamically via code or by manually setting the positions in the designer.
2. Use a single, tall "containing" view in your Scroll View. Make *that* view, say, 1500 its tall. In the designer, add the first few elements, then set the Y position of that view to a negative number. If your Scroll View is 500 its tall, set the Y position of the containing view to -400. The view will "slide up" in the Scroll View, and you can continue adding elements.